# Which the compatible version of spring batch with spring 3.0.x and hibernate 3.6.3?

Tags: spring, hibernate, version, spring-batch

i'm using spring version 3.0.5 and hibernate-core version 3.6.3.final, hiberanate-commons-annotations-3.2.0.final and hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.0.final.jar and i want to know which version is compatible ? 
I can"t modify the versions of spring and hibernate at the moment. For technical problems hibernate4 not support HibernateTemplate and spring version great than 3.0.x not support HibernateDaoSupport too.

So I want the spring batch version that is compatible with these two versios.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `spring-batch-2.1.9.RELEASE` it is compatible with `spring-core 3.0.x`.
From 2.2.0 spring-Batch needs `spring-core 3.2.0`

Comment: thank u for ur response if i upgrade spring-core 3.0.x to spring-core 3.2.0 i need to change my code because i'am using HibernateDaosupport ?

Comment: I don't know. Why you think so?

Comment: because spring-core 3.2.x dont support HibernateDaoSupport

Comment: I changed the version of spring batch to spring-batch-2.1.9 and it works but must to upgrade spring version and hibernate because its to old.
Thank u