# Spring Batch 4.3.8 compatible with spring framework 3.0.5?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I need to know if springbatch(4.3.8) is or anyhow can be made compatible with springframework 3.0.5. I am getting an error if using.

The error being obj.getclass() is null. But nothing is passed as null.

Code I cant display over here as it will be a policy violation of the company.

Tried with 5.0.1 but seems like it will be a huge change.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, Spring Batch 4 requires Java 8 but Spring Framework 3 only supports 1.5, 6 and 7 so I don't think you can make this work.

Comment: I guess @Lucifer meant Spring Boot 3.0.5?

Comment: You don't need to share the company code but how shell we understand the issue? Please provide a simplified version of code causing this "obj.getclass() is null' error.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.8/reference/html/whatsnew.html#dependencyUpdates) says that Spring Batch 4.3.8 depends on Spring Framework 5.3. If you need compatibility with an older version of Spring Framework you would need to use an older version of Spring Batch, like it is mentioned in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43846616/721855.